# Android "no such table" on some devices

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I am having problems with external database. The database works fine on around 60% of devices, but for example on Nexus 7 and HTC it throws "no such table" error in logcat. I am pretty confused what to do with it.
However I AM VERY SURE THAT THE TABLE EXISTS. And it works on my devices at home.

DataBaseHelper Class

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_QUOTE = "quote";
public static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
public static final String TABLE_QUOTES = "quotes";
public static final String KEY_FAV = "fav";


private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.radoman.gameofthrones/databases/";

private final Context myContext;



private static String DB_NAME = "database.db";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 



public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {



    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 11 );
    this.myContext = context;


}   



public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();

        try {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

private boolean checkDataBase(){

    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();


}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);


}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    try {
        createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("copy_db", "Error copying database");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}



//CRUD

    public void addQuote(Quote quote)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUOTE, quote.getQuote());
        values.put(KEY_AUTHOR, quote.getAuthor());

        db.insert(TABLE_QUOTES, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public Quote getQuote(int id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_QUOTES, new String[] {KEY_ID,KEY_QUOTE,KEY_AUTHOR,KEY_FAV}, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Quote quote = new Quote(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getInt(3));

        return quote;
    }

    public List<Quote> getAllQuotes()
    {
            List<Quote> quoteList = new ArrayList<Quote>();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUOTES;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do 
                {
                    Quote quote = new Quote();
                    quote.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    quote.setQuote(cursor.getString(1));
                    quote.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2));
                    quoteList.add(quote);
                } while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            return quoteList;
    }

    public int ifFav(int id)

    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_QUOTES, new String[] {KEY_ID,KEY_QUOTE,KEY_AUTHOR,KEY_FAV}, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Quote quote = new Quote(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getInt(3));

        if (quote.getFav() == 1)
        {
            db.close();
            return 1;
        }

        else
        {
            db.close();
            return 0;
        }



    }

    public void addFav(int id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "UPDATE quotes SET fav=1 WHERE _id=" +id;
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.close();


    }

    public void nullFav(int id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "UPDATE quotes SET fav=0 WHERE _id=" +id;
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.close();
    }

    public List<HashMap<String, String>> getCharQuote(String character)
    {

        String selectQuery;
        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        if(character.equals("All quotes"))
        {
            selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUOTES;
        }
        else if (character.equals("Other characters"))
        {
            selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_QUOTES+ 
                " WHERE author NOT IN('Syrio Forel','Ned Stark','Daenerys Targaryen'" +
                ",'Margaery Tyrell','Robert Baratheon','Tyrion Lannister','Ser Jorah        Mormont','Bran Stark','Cersei Lannister','Jaime Lannister');";
        }
        else
        {

             selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUOTES+" WHERE author='"+character+"'";
        }
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do 
            {

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("quote", cursor.getString(2));
                map.put("fav", cursor.getString(0));
                map.put("id",cursor.getString(1));
                fillMaps.add(map);

            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return fillMaps;

    }

    public List<HashMap<String, String>> getAllFavQuote()
    {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUOTES+" WHERE fav=1";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do 
            {

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("quote", cursor.getString(2));
                map.put("id", cursor.getString(1));
                fillMaps.add(map);

            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return fillMaps;

    }
```

}

And logcat error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.radoman.gameofthrones/com.radoman.gameofthrones.FavQuotesActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: quotes (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE fav=1
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: quotes (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE fav=1
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
at com.radoman.gameofthrones.DataBaseHelper.getAllFavQuote(DataBaseHelper.java:290)
at com.radoman.gameofthrones.FavQuotesActivity.onCreate(FavQuotesActivity.java:72)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
... 11 more
```

Comment: I just wander why are you passing DB_NAME and not DB_PATH to your super constructor?

Comment: Hard coded database path seems to be a bad idea. Why not use the SQLiteDatabase object provided in the onCreate to create tables.

Comment: I suspect that the DB isn't where you think it is.

Comment: It is where i suspect it is. It is supposed to pass DB_NAME. What do you mean SQLiteDatabase object?

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed older version of your app, when the table is not been presented, just installing the new version won't replace the old database. Uninstall the app from the device and install the newer one should work. Or make implementation of the `onUpgrade` trigger.

**EDIT:**

you might also try to replace this line:

```
myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

with this:

```
myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
```

Comment: Fresh and first time install.

Comment: you might also try to open the database with NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS instead of READWRITE. I think I had problem with this too, check the edited answer.